# Limiting how much data Backbone.js fetch()'es?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I'm currently making improvements and bug-fixes on a client's backbone.js app that someone else wrote. The app is a web store and an inventory management system. Currently, the app features an infinite scroll with all of the store's items that loads dynamically but allows for searching and filtering. On the initial page load, it does a fetch() on an item collection and pulls about 2.7 MB from the RESTful api with a GET() request. This is not ideal. Over time, this dataset will grow larger. The current dataset makes the page take 6-10 seconds to load on most broadband connections in my area (nyc).

All of the backbone.js tutorials and documentation that I've come across so far teach pulling an entire collection of items with fetch(). Is there a way to break up thie collection and have the front-end only pull chunks from the back-end when necessary?

Comment: You will have to have server side's support to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There are plugin/extensions that allow for paging of collections.

E.g. https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator or https://github.com/wyuenho/backbone-pageable